# Why doesn't this code with XMLHttpRequest and document.write work?

Tags: javascript, ajax

my code:

```
var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
req.open("GET","http://http://surfkid.redio.de/link.php");
req.send(null);
var textout = var.responseText;
document.write(textout);
```

On the document, there is no text.

What i have made wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
req.open("GET","http://http://surfkid.redio.de/link.php");
```

1. has a spurious extra `http://`. In any case, this won't work unless the current web page itself is served from surfkid.redio.de, due to the Same Origin Policy, so assuming that to be the case, you don't need to specify the server name at all. (If this is not the case, you're going to have to read up on JSONP.)
2. Is an asynchronous XMLHttpRequest. The response to this request will not be available straight away; you have to add an event listener to `req.onreadystatechange`.

The alternative is to pass an extra `, false` argument to `open()`, to get a synchronous request. But synchronous XMLHttpRequest is generally considered a Bad Thing, because it locks up the browser UI until the response has been fetched.

```
var textout = var.responseText;
```

You meant `req`.

```
document.write(textout);
```

`document.write` is generally best avoided. For one, it obliterates the current document if called after its content is completely loaded, which will be the case if you use a callback on an asynchronous XMLHttpRequest.

Easier to write the `responseText` to an element's `innerHTML` (assuming the response is supposed to be markup; if not create a Text node with the given text value).

```
<div id="redio-link"></div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    // Fix up missing XMLHttpRequest in IE6. You only need to do this once.
    //
    if (!window.XMLHttpRequest && 'ActiveXObject' in window) window.XMLHttpRequest= function() {
        return new ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHttp');
    };

    // Fetch link
    //
    var req= new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange= function() {
        if (this.readyState===4)
            document.getElementById('redio-link').innerHTML= this.responseText;
    };
    req.open('GET', '/link.php');
    req.send();
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

you cant get `var.responseText`, you have to get it from the request.

Also `document.write` is a function, so pass it the string from the request object.

`document.write(req.responseText)`

But honestly, look to using a framework like [jquery](http://jquery.com/) it will save you time in the long run.

```
$.ajax({ url: "http://http://surfkid.redio.de/link.php", context: document.body, success: function(data){
        document.write(data);
      }});
```

Comment: That is why you need to use a framework like jquery. Otherwise you have to deal with a million browser incompatibilities.

Comment: dont work....... <script src="http://http://surfkid.redio.de/j.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

Answer (score 0):

:fixed code.. you're not handling ay return... also, when I try to get your script I get an error so I substituted my own page.

```
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.onreadystatechange = function() {
        // in case of network errors this might not give reliable results
        if(this.readyState == 4)
            document.write(this.responseText);
    }

    req.open("GET","http://api.fatherstorm.com/test/redio_result.php");
    req.send();
```